# StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable with tuple of Table in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

i want to know if it is possible to Make a DataStream of type

```
DataStream<Tuple4<String, Charge, List<Charge>, Table>>
```

with the **Table** type inside the tuple the table is from Table Api of Flink, i'm trying to pass the variable **accumulatorTable** which is the flink table inside a process function to return the tuple like this:

```
DataStream<Tuple4<String, Charge, List<Charge>, Table>> joinStream =
            currentStreamByKeys
                    .connect(historicStreamByKeys)
                    .flatMap(new LeftJoin())
                    .process(new ProcessFunction<Tuple2<Charge, List<Charge>>, Tuple4<String, Charge, List<Charge>, Table>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void processElement(Tuple2<Charge, List<Charge>> value, Context ctx, Collector<Tuple4<String, Charge, List<Charge>, Table>> out) throws Exception {
                            out.collect(
                                    new Tuple4<>(
                                            KeysExtractor.getKey(keys,value.f0),
                                            value.f0,
                                            value.f1,
                                            accumulatorTable
                                    )
                            );
                        }
                    })
                    .keyBy(0);
```

But i'm getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.InvalidProgramException: The implementation of the StreamExecutionEnvironment is not serializable. The object probably contains or references non serializable fields.
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Flink maybe using TypeHints?, Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is that the `Table` from Flink ??

Comment: Yeah From Table Api

Comment: Why would You use the table in `DataStream` ? What exacly is your use-case there ?